# sql referenced integer in multiple bit totals

Tags: mysql, bit-manipulation

We have table of bitwise types that we use for typifying accounts. Each account can have child 'types'.

```
Table: types

id | title | int | types | family
1    foo     1     7       ?
2    bar     2     1       ?
3    baz     4     3       ?
```

We've been using this table for a long time and it works well because the counts can never go over 20. (There is an account id column left out for clarity.)

It's trivial to get a list of id's using 'int' & 'types'. But how would I get a types family? (Where each type is referenced in the 'types' column.) In the example above record 2 family would be (int 1+ int 4) = 5 because its referenced in records 1 and 3 'types' (because 7 and 3 both have the 2 bit set).

I might need to clarify

Comment: I for one have no clue what the meaning of these columns is. "bitwise", "typifying", "counts can never go over 20", ... sorry, but I am not following you.

Comment: I also can't figure out what you're asking. I think you're talking about bit masks, but I don't understand what you mean by "record 2 family would be (int 1 + int 4) = 5". Is it because `7` and `3` both have the `2` bit set?

Comment: Maybe a self-join on `t1.int & t2.types != 0`?

Comment: @Barmar - Yes because 7 and 3 both have the 2 bit set. I've edited my question to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this query will do what you want. It SUMs the `int` values for each row where the `types` value includes the `int` value of the target row:

```
SELECT t1.*, SUM(t2.int) AS family
FROM types t1
JOIN types t2 ON t2.types & t1.int != 0
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.title, t1.int, t1.types
```

Output:

```
id  title   int     types   family
1   foo     1       7       7
2   bar     2       1       5
3   baz     4       3       1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fycxaR24nizdbr3RAj7bg4/0)